# Is there any way to work with ESMTP using .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, smtp

I like to send mail from a domain which is using ESMTP. I am using smtp client in c# 3.5 but getting response 5.5.2

My code is like

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
{
     Host = txtHost.Text.Trim(),
     Port = Convert.ToInt32(txtport.Text.Trim()),
     EnableSsl = chkEnableSSL.Checked,
     DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
     Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(your_id, your_password),
     UseDefaultCredentials = false,
     Timeout = 100000,
};
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(your_id, txtTo.Text.Trim(), txtSubject.Text, txtBody.Text);
client.Send(mm);
```

Are there any way to work with ESMTP using .Net 3.5 ?